# SG 90 servos randomly spinning

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, servo, stm32

I started one project where i need 4 servos to control 4 grabbers jaws. i use STM32F103C8T6 with arduino IDE for programming it. The motor TZT Micro Servo 9g SG 90. First, I was playing with stepper motors to make them rotate how I want, then I added one servo on the same protoboard where are steppers and drivers for each. I used servo sweep example, and it randomly started twitching and sometimes to spin until power is off. the STM is powered with usb cable from PC. Then i tried other 3 motors and got same result.

Then i put STM on separate protoboard and there connected servo and it was not perfect but it was much stable than on onther protoboard. Then i used old PC power supply which i modified long time ago to have jacks for 12V, 5V and 3,3V, and connected servo to it and it worked normally.

So I started connecting motors 1 by one back to protoboard with other elements and tested them while adding them, first the first one , then added second and tested both, then added 3rd and tested all 3...

First two worked fine, but when i added third, all of them started twitching again, but then it stopped. So i added fourth and now all of them are twitching even if I write in code to rotate only one or two of them, which I don't understand how they can move if I do not give them signal from code.

Here is code for controlling both servo and stepper motors:

```
#include<Servo.h>

const int stepPin1 = PA4;
const int dirPin1 = PA0; 
const int stepPin2 = PA5;
const int dirPin2 = PA1;

const int stepPin3 = PA6; 
const int dirPin3 = PA2;

const int stepPin4 = PA7; 
const int dirPin4 = PA3;

Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
Servo servo3;
Servo servo4;

void setup() {
  pinMode(stepPin1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepPin2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepPin3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepPin4,OUTPUT);
   
  pinMode(dirPin1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin4,OUTPUT);

  servo1.attach(PB12);
  servo2.attach(PB14);
  servo3.attach(PA8);
  servo4.attach(PA10);

  //servo1.write(0);
  //servo2.write(0);
  //servo3.write(0);
  //servo4.write(0);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(dirPin1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dirPin2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dirPin3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dirPin4,HIGH);

   //servo1.write(100);
   servo2.write(100);
   //servo3.write(100);
   //servo4.write(100);

  for(int x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(stepPin2,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(stepPin3,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(stepPin4,HIGH);

    delayMicroseconds(750); 

    digitalWrite(stepPin1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin4,LOW); 

    delayMicroseconds(750);
  }

  delay(1000); // One second delay
  
  digitalWrite(dirPin1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(dirPin2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(dirPin3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(dirPin4,LOW);

  //servo1.write(-100);
  servo2.write(-100);
  //servo3.write(-100);
  //servo4.write(100);

  for(int x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(stepPin2,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(stepPin3,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(stepPin4,HIGH);

    delayMicroseconds(750);

    digitalWrite(stepPin1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin4,LOW);

    delayMicroseconds(750);
  }

  delay(1000);

}
```

[Here is also link to a short video of how the servos are behaving:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FaKXvKQmiXgVDbzvWSbjzkILVPN4dsSE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do the servos still twitch if the steppers are quiet ? If the stepper-drivers are disconnected?

Comment: Yes, they are twitching. Soon I should get another STM and Arduino uno to test board and motors to check if they are broken.

Comment: Try assigning pins to the servos that are physically distant on the Arduino board from those assigned to steppers. Does anything change? It's looks rather like crosstalk from one to the other.

Comment: They are already separated because pins for stepper motors are on one side of board and servo pins are on another. Btw i managed to get both arduino and another STM from friend. I tested only servo motors on arduino alone with separated power supply, and only once one motor started spinning continuously until power supply is off. Next I will try same with STM and if it works, I will put it back on protoboard with other elements. But first I need to sleep after being awake all night, so I will update situation after some time.

Comment: With second STM it doesn't work too. When I added first servo, it started twitching, then i tried other 3 and then I tried them on other pins but its same. Maybe they would work if I would use software for STM, but this was easier way for me. So because it works on arduino (I tested them now again), I will probably buy arduino nano and use it just to control servos with them, MEGA is expensive here where I live and i do not have much time left so I have to use 2 controllers for this...
Anyway, thanks :D

Comment: Not necessarily on topic, but I could swear I saw the front servo in the video turn 360°; did it? As far as I know, the SG90 servos only do about 180°.

Comment: Just got arduino nano and it worked perfectly fine. So only problem that I see now is probably that Arduino IDE and arduino libraries are not fully compatible with STM chips and that is why that happened to me.
Anyway, thanks for help

Comment: ocrdu, sorry for late answer. Yeah it did 360°, sometimes it was going more than 360°. But if you make mods on those servos, than they can be continuous servos, so it isnt impossible. But my problem was that they all did it without mods and i was totally confused how is that happening xD